# node-sass installation cannot find installed msvs_version

Tags: c++, windows, npm, node-sass

I am trying to install node-sass via npm `>> npm install node-sass`.

I have Visual Studio 2010 installed on my system (for reasons) and I have found out, that I need the C++ compilers from Visual Studio 2013 or higher.
I tried to install the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages für Visual Studio 2013 and then run `>> npm install --msvs_version=2013 node-sass`. But I get the error:

> Specified platform toolset (v120) is not installed or invalid.

But on installing the Redistributable it says version 12.0.30501. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The Path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets` does not include a v120 folder only v90 and v100. So I am guessing the problem is, that the Redistributable does not install correctly?

Comment: You are making a confusion between redistributable and toolset. The redistributable is just a series of DLLs (the CRT and MFC runtimes). The toolset is composed of the actual tools to build. It's not possible to install the v120 toolset as stand alone, without Visual Studio. You can do that with v140 and v141, AFAIR.

Comment: Yes! That is what I was confused about... I installed the standalone toolset for VS 2015 which created the folder ...MSBuild/v14.0. By changing to --msvs_version=2015 it works! 
If you put it together into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have this answered, I will put @Marius Bancila's comment into an answer.

The issue is that the redistributables are just some DLLs for runtime. The toolset does actually include the tools to build. 
For v120 it is not possible to install the toolset without Visual Studio. From v140 (Visual Studio 2015) onwards it is possible to install also the Toolset as a standalone without VS.